# Is Shared can have references to Server And client in blazor WASM app?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, webassembly

I have blazor webassembly project with server project.

Client (wasm),
Server (MVC),
Shared,

What I want to do is to create in my enum a list of controllers like this

```
public enum EnumControllersList
{
    [Display(Name = nameof(Web.Server.SchedulerController))]
    SchedulerController
...
}
```

Then I can use it in my custom URL like this :

```
    public Uri Action(EnumControllersList enumControllersList, EnumActionList action, object prms)
    {
        var baseRoute = $"{EnumHelper<EnumControllersList>.GetDisplayValue(enumControllersList)}/{EnumHelper<EnumActionList>.GetDisplayValue(action)}";
        if (routeValues == null)
        {
            return new Uri(baseRoute);
        }

        var queryString = ToQueryString(prms);
        return new Uri($"{baseRoute}?{queryString}");
```

}

Then I can use this command to easy build url

```
Uri CreateAppointmentUri = _urlBuilderHelper.Action(EnumControllersList.SchedulerController, EnumActionList.CreateAppointment);
```

And I can be 100% safe that if action/controller rename will occur, front-end will use not updated values and will throw 404 or something worse.

I used this technique previously but when I'm trying to work with WASM + server I have big doubts about this because client and server shouldn't reference each other directly.

Comment: Create a class library, put `EnumControllersList` in it, reference the class library from both client and server.

Comment: Shared = Shared.  Both projects have access to the code in shared, so add share code to the Shared Library.

Comment: What I mean is little different, Shared  is Shared  but in my case this relation is in different direction, because usually client and servers have relation to shared, but in my case Shared have relation to Server too! This is big deal because client is WASM it's mean client will run on client device, and theoretically can be decompiled. Usually it's not a big deal decompiling client, but in my case shared has reference to server, it's mean dll from there will be included in client, and this is already big deal for me due to the security software vulnerabilities and copyrights.